# Add banner after the third post

Tags: wp-query

How do I add a banner or a DIV with content after the third post on the index or category of Wordpress 4.0?

```
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next page navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );


            endif;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to WordPress at all, it's a generic PHP question, hence off-topic here. It's easy, follow the inline comments, and you can have it. :)

```
<?php
//declare a counter
$counter = 1;

// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

/*
 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
 */
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

//check the counter and display your content
if( $counter === 3 ) { ?>
    <div class="third-div-in-loop">content</div>
<?php }

//update the counter on every loop
$counter++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Perfect, he's right. What if I want to set this only for certain categories, the is_category solve?

Comment: Why do you question first, and not try first? :) Yap, it will. :)